# Alias Multiple Commands in Linux

Tags: linux, git, bash, alias, website-deployment

I am managing a website using `git`. One of the requirements for the `git repository` is that `bare = true`. It uses a post-receive hook to manage pushes from my local computer. The problem is that sometimes I would like to make changes to a WordPress directory on my website using the wp-admin view online. So then I would just `ssh` into the directory and run `git --work-tree="BLAH" add .` and `git --work-tree="BLAH" commit -m "BLAH"`. Is there a way to set up an alias, like `alias git="git --work-tree=\"BLAH\""` and have that work for all `git` commands?

Comment: aliases are only suitable for static values and actions, i.e. `alias workDir='cd $workDir'` . When you want to process arguments you need to use functions. Search here for `[bash] function` and you'll find 100's of examples. Good luck.

Comment: To be honest the best way not to screw up deployment is to automatise it, Takes a look at Capistrano for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is curious how I solved it (thanks to [shellter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908671/alias-multiple-commands-in-linux/39908716?noredirect=1#comment67102599_39908671)), I wrote a bash script then prompted the user for input like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
function fix {
        git --work-tree="PATH_TO_WORKING_TREE" $1
}
echo -n "git "
read -e INPUT
until [ "$INPUT" = "quit" ]; do
        fix $INPUT
        echo -n "git "
        read -e INPUT
done
```

Running it:

```
user@server [repo.git] $ git-fix
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
git quit
```

Answer (score 2):

There are times when `alias` are a great tool. Then there are times when things start getting too complicated where a shell script is better.

To create a single command that executes other commands just create a file (maybe call it `git-add-all`) then type the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

git --work-tree="BLAH" add .
git --work-tree="BLAH" commit -m "BLAH"
```

Then you can run the script by simply doing:

```
bash git-add-all
```

Even better, make the script executable:

```
chmod +x git-add-all
```

Then you can use it like any command:

```
./git-add-all
```

---

#### Advanced tips:

To be able to run the script from any git directory you can copy/move the file to one of the directories in your `$PATH`. For example `/usr/loca/bin`. Then you can simply run `git-add-all` instead of `./git-add-all`.

Even better is to create your own personal scripts directory and include it in `$PATH`. I personally use `~/bin`. To add the directory to `$PATH` you just need to add the following to `.bashrc` or `.profile`:

```
export PATH=/home/username/bin:$PATH
```

or if you're doing this for the root user:

```
export PATH=/root/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `.bashrc` file in `Linux`. You can edit it for creating `alias` for your favorite and frequently used commands.

To create an alias permanently add the alias to your .bashrc file

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

The alias should look like:

```
alias al='cmd'
```

You can read more about it over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias).

Comment: I know about .bashrc and already tried that. When I run `git` it expands it, but if the command has two parts (like `git status`) it won't expand it.

Comment: try naming your alias other than `git`. For example, ll is an alias of `ls -alF`. It still works if you type `ll -h` or `ll -a`.